# Source in shell script doesn't work when script called with arguments

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a shell script that will start Xilinx programs for me, but I am having a problem with the source command. Here is my script called `xilinx`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd /home/sclukey/Xilinx
source /opt/Xilinx/14.6/ISE_DS/settings32.sh
$@
```

If I just call `xilinx` the script returns

```
. /opt/Xilinx/14.6/ISE_DS/common/.settings32.sh /opt/Xilinx/14.6/ISE_DS/common
. /opt/Xilinx/14.6/ISE_DS/EDK/.settings32.sh /opt/Xilinx/14.6/ISE_DS/EDK
. /opt/Xilinx/14.6/ISE_DS/PlanAhead/.settings32.sh /opt/Xilinx/14.6/ISE_DS/PlanAhead
. /opt/Xilinx/14.6/ISE_DS/ISE/.settings32.sh /opt/Xilinx/14.6/ISE_DS/ISE
```

but if I run `xilinx ise` then the output of the `source` command is missing and it just returns

```
/usr/local/bin/xilinx: line 4: ise: command not found
```

I believe this is because the source command is not running when the script is called with arguments. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Thanks

EDIT:
I've discovered it is because the `settings32.sh` file uses the `$1` argument, and when the `xilinx` script is called with arguments, those arguments also get passed to the `source` command which breaks the `settings32.sh` script. So how can I stop the arguments from getting passed to the `source` command?

Comment: What do you expect the line `$@` to do? What do you expect passing the argument `ise` to your script to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `/opt/Xilinx/14.6/ISE_DS/settings32.sh` or one of the scripts it `source`'s responds to command-line argument and swallows them. Try saving them before sourcing, then wiping them:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
args=$@
shift

cd /home/sclukey/Xilinx
source /opt/Xilinx/14.6/ISE_DS/settings32.sh

$args
```

Comment: No luck, the script works the same with `#!/bin/sh` and `.` as with the bash stuff. Also saving the arguments does not help.

Comment: @Clukester: what if you rename `args` to something like `my_args_stay_off`? One of the scripts might be using `args` for its own data.

Comment: It still doesn't work. The arguments are not swallowed because it does try to run `ise` command. It is simply that the `source` command has not set up the path properly. The `source` command only works when the script is run with no arguments

Comment: @Clukester: what if you save `$@`, wipe it, `source`, then run `$args`?

Comment: @Clukester: try `shift`.

Comment: success! thanks. If you add the shift to your answer I'll accept

Answer (score 0):

With your script, you are automating the following commands, if `xilinx ise` is typed in from the command line:

```
$ cd /home/sclukey/Xilinx
$ source /opt/Xilinx/14.6/ISE_DS/settings32.sh
$ ise
```

The response from the script indicates that there's no `ise` program in the path. I would check to see where `ise` is, and if `settings32.sh` sets up a path for it.

Comment: `env bash` does not clear the environment; that's `env -`. Try `env printenv` and `env - printenv`.

Comment: I changed `#!/usr/bin/env bash` to `#!/bin/bash` and nothing changed. Also, manually sourcing the `settings32.sh` file then running `ise` does start the program, so the path is set correctly by `settings32.sh`